# video-js not working on my PCs

Tags: html, video, video-streaming

I uploaded to my website, "demo.html" that comes with Video-js download. I also have my own MP4 uploaded to my site.

First, I ran demo as is and the Ocean video ran fine. Then I changed the `<source src="...">` tag to my own movie and it wouldn't load (get the spinning circle, time is 0:00 / 0:00). I used absolute addressing (i.e. "http://www.mysite/..").

This is using IE10, Firefox (the latest ver) and Chrome on two PCs using Windows 7 & 8.

This is an indication that the problem is with the server; the movie on videojs.com runs but the same code (with an edited "src=") doesn't work on my server.

I ran the edited demo.html on a MAC (OS 10.6) and my movie loads and runs fine, so the code is ok and, instead, indicates the problem is with PCs.

Would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: In your title, you mention IE10 (actually it said, !E10 originally), but in the body you say that it doesn't work in any browser. Can you clarify this by either removing the mention from the title, or saying which browsers it does work in?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I should have changed the title. I also forgot to mention that I've tried it on TWO pcs, the other running Windows 8. I've tried IE10, Firefox (latest ver) and Chrome. None of them work on either PC.

Comment: That is helpful information, feel free to edit this back into the answer to provide clarification for any future readers.

Comment: Tx. I added those details and simplified the explanation.

Comment: have you checked with something like Fiddler to make sure the video is being successfully requested and has the right MIME type? Was the Ocean video on your site or somewhere else?

Comment: The Ocean video is on the home page of videojs.com, not my site.